# Retrieving user information in Azure Function (C#) from Angular-cli application

Tags: c#, azure, angular-cli, azure-functions, adal

I'm having troubles retrieving user information inside an Azure Function and have no idea how to do this. I've tried different things already, but nothing seems to work...

First of all, I created an Angular-cli application and am able to login using the "adal-angular5" npm-package.

When I want to retrieve information from a HttpTriggering Azure function, I can't seem to find how to get more information about the user using the token from the angular app (or how to validate the logged in user). I'm including it in the headers of the message.

```
headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.adal5Service.userInfo.token}`);
```

I've created an app registration in Azure AD including my reply URL, Permissions to "Microsoft Graph" and "Windows Azure Active Directory"

Does anyone know how to do this? (If more information should be necessary to solve... just tell me, and I'll happily provide that)

**Things I tried already**

Code below with both requestUrl's (one is in comment) and with/without sending the token in the header

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    //var requestUrl = $"https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version=1.6";
    var requestUrl = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/";

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
    var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AdUser>(responseString);
    return user;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean inside the function ? Can you share your existing code, what you already tried ?

Comment: @Thomas: Indeed, from INSIDE the function. I'll add it to the question

Comment: have you read this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stuartleeks/2018/02/19/azure-functions-and-app-service-authentication/ ?

Comment: What error messages are you getting with the code you are executing?